# difference between Jquery timestamp and php timestamp?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

is there a difference between Jquery's timestamp and php/sql's time stamp?

I've got two timestamps-- the PHP one is:

```
1394488721
```

while the Jquery one is:

```
139449051952
```

They're very similar--but obviously the jquery one is a bit longer.

I'm trying to use both these to sync an $.load function that loads some information from the DB every time a cron job is run

Comment: I'm guessing the JS time stamp is in miliseconds and PHP in seconds. What functions are you using?

Comment: the PHP time is strtotime and the Jquery time is $.now() @Barell

Comment: I suggest you to read documentation before you will ask a question next time.

Answer (score 4):

Timestamps in jQuery (as returned by [`$.now`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/), which defers to [`Date.prototype.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)) JavaScript are expressed in milliseconds. In PHP, (using `time` et al) they are in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) object is based on milliseconds, whereas PHP's (as generated by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)) is based in seconds.

Also, there may be timezone differences to account for, I believe JavaScript will use the current timezone for the computer by default (e.g. the "browser's timezone") while PHP's is likely based off of the timezone defined in the PHP configuration file (or the user's timezone, if you are setting and using that on a domain model somehow).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the PHP timestamp by `1000` to create a new Javascript timestamp based on it:

```
JS Timestamp := PHP Timestamp * 1000
```

This JS Timestamp is in milliseconds, so you can compare with other JS `Date()` values.

Answer (score 0):

To get a matching PHP time try.

```
<?php echo microtime(); ?>
```

Comment: `microtime()` returns microseconds not milliseconds.

Comment: `round(microtime(true) * 1000)` returns timestamp as milliseconds