# How to compare mysql timestamp with jquery timestamp?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a timestamp value which return from mysql table. Now I need compare it with jquery timestamp to check whether time and date expired or not.

Comment: there is no jQuery timestamp...

Comment: Format your date in jquery

Comment: How do they look like?

Comment: I have data like 2015-08-29 00:00:00 (Its from DB). But jquery return date value like this -> 13898736000

Comment: Your Jquery date is a timestamp. Just convert either one to the other... In PHP: $ts = strtotime(2015-08-29 00:00:00);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this stackoverflow answer we get: [difference between Jquery timestamp and php timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312759/difference-between-jquery-timestamp-and-php-timestamp)

> Timestamps in jQuery (as returned by $.now, which defers to
>   Date.prototype.getTime) JavaScript are expressed in milliseconds. In
>   PHP, (using time et al) they are in seconds.

So, we can write something like:

```
$time_php = strtotime(2015-08-29 00:00:00);
$time_js = 13898736000 * 1000;
if($time_php > $time_js) {
     echo"php time greater";
 }
 else{ echo"js time greater";}
```